# Discord.JS | AwaitReaction in DM

Tags: discord.js

I don't want bots to join my server and advertise in chat or dm's of users, so I thought I'll let new users react to a message, and after that my bot will send them a question in dm's, if they answer correctly he should give them the verified role. The bot can send the message, but after that an error appears.

```
(node:12356) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined
```

I dont know how to solve this, because in the Docs channel.type exists.

Here is the code

```js
client.on('messageReactionAdd', async (reaction, user) =>{
    const filter = m => true

    if (reaction.message.partials) await reaction.message.fetch();
    if (reaction.partials) await reaction.fetch();

    if (user.bot) return;
    if (!reaction.message.guild) return;

    if (reaction.message.id === '814035246399488001'){
        if (reaction.emoji.name === '✅'){
            user.send("What is the subtrahend of 156 - 123?")
            .catch(()=>{console.log('couldnt send a DM')})
            if ( channel.type === 'dm' )
            user.dmChannel.awaitMessages(filter, {
                max:1,
                time:30000,
                error:["time"]
            })
            .then(collected => {
                if (collected.first().content === "33"){
                    reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add('779523805492019254')         
                    if(err => {
                        console.log(err)
                    });
                }else{
                    user.send("this is not the correct answer, you will not get verified.")
                    return;
                }
            })
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Where did you define `channel`? It's usually `message.channel.type`

Comment: I tried that before too, but then it said `Cannot read property 'channel' of undefined`

Comment: Well, I assume your `if (channel.type === 'dm')` is within the `onReaction` event and not within `onMessage`. Thus, message is undefined. And so is channel. You need to "catch" the users answer inside `client.on("message", () => ...)`

Comment: Uhm, i don't think i understand what you mean with "You need to "catch" the users answer inside `client.on("message", () => ...)`"

Comment: Once the user replies to the bot's DM, you can't catch that event in your reaction code above. You need to catch it [inside the message event](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/Client?scrollTo=e-message).

Comment: So, should i, after i've checked the reaction and sent the DM, make a new `client.on('message' ...` event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have asked around in some discord servers and found the solution:

```
if (reaction.emoji.name === '✅'){
            let msg = await user.send("What is the subtrahend of 156 - 123?")
            .catch(()=>{console.log('couldnt send a DM')})
            if (msg.channel.type == `dm`)
```

What i think happens is, the bot now knows that `msg.channel.type` is the channel where he sent the message before, and yeah, i am so happy now that it works :3 and thank you too NullDev your comment lead to the solution too <3